# Are all parameters required when creating a contract?

Tags: daml

When creating a contract from a template, are all the parameters required? What if some fields need to be entered later?

```
 template Exp
   with
    member1 : Party
    member2 : Party
    comment : Text
  where
    signatory : member1

  choice ABC : ()
    with 
      anotherParty : Party
    controller member1
      do create this with member2 = anotherParty
      pure()
```

If I want to leave member2 blank when creating the contract, how do I do that? Is it a good pattern or there is better way to work around the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All fields are required. There is no equivalent of `null` in daml. If you want fields to be optional, use the `Optional` type. In your case declare `member2 : Optional Party`. The `Optional` type can take values `None` or `Some p` where `p: Party`. The first time you create an instance of `Exp`, you can set `member2` to `None` and then in you choice `do create this with member2 = Some anotherParty`.